# Images not shown on Iphone, but are shown on dekstop or on android phones

Tags: html, iphone

I have an online website. There is a specific page in which 3 specific images are shown.
I can see these pictures in my android phone (Android9 GalaxyS8) and on my computer browser, but I can't view these pictures in my Iphone(XR), neither in Chrome browser nor Safari browser. Why is that?
This is the HTML of these 3 pictures:

```
<img class="changeProfilePictureFormUploadLabel__img" src="images/website_general/profileuploadimage.png">
<input class="changeProfilePictureUploadSubmit" type="image" name="profile[upload]" src="images/website_general/submitpicture.png">
<input id="changeProfilePictureFormDelete" class="changeProfilePictureFormDelete" type="image" src="images/website_general/deleteprofileimage.png" name="profile[delete]">
```

3 Images on computer browser:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiUCI.png)

3 Images on Android phone:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tu16U.png)

3 Images on Iphone (which are not shown..):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZIGCH.png)